# Eigenvalues of a tridiagonal stochastic matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

I've tried to calculate the eigenvalues of this tridiagonal (stochastic) matrix of dimension $n \times n$, but I had some problems to find an explicit form. I only know that 1 is the largest eigenvalue.

$$M=\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
 1& 1 &  &  &  & \\ 
 1& 0 &1  &  &  & \\ 
 & 1 & 0 &1  &  & \\ 
 &  &  & \dots &  & \\ 
 &  &  & 1 & 0 & 1\\ 
 &  &  &  & 1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$$

(Here, the matrix takes the value 0 where there is no number.)

I'm interested in the value of the second largest eigenvalue as a function of the dimension $n$ of this matrix. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a matrix so nicely structured, I will bet that it has been studied thoroughly, but we can do the analysis by ourselves. Let
$$
P=\pmatrix{1&-1\\ &\ddots&\ddots\\ &&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&\ddots&-1\\ &&&&1}.
$$
Then
$$
PMP^{-1}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc|c}
0&\tfrac12&&\\
\tfrac12&\ddots&\ddots\\
&\ddots&\ddots&\tfrac12\\
&&\tfrac12&0\\
\hline
&&&\tfrac12&1\\
\end{array}\right)
=\pmatrix{C&0\\ \tfrac12e_{n-1}^\top&1}.
$$
$C$ belongs to the class of symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrices. Explicit formula for eigen-decompositions of such matrices are known (cf. the [lecture notes written by the late Gene Golub](http://www.stat.uchicago.edu/~lekheng/courses/302/notes14.pdf)). In particular, the eigenvalues of $C$ are $\cos(k\pi/n)\ (k=1,\,2,\,\ldots,\,n-1)$ and hence the two second largest-sized eigenvalues of $M$ are $\pm\cos(\pi/n)$.

Answer (score 2):

The second largest eigenvalue is $\cos(\pi /n)$.

hint: show that the eigenvalues are the $\cos(k\pi/n), k=0\cdots n-1$.

Comment: Hi, could you please add some explanation why this is the case, or give a reference?