# Eigenvectors of a tridiagonal stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices

I'm looking for the eigenvectors of this matrix:

\begin{equation}
\nonumber
M =
\frac{1}{N} \left( \begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 0 & 1 &&&&&&&\\ 
N &  0 & 2&&&&&&& \\
&N-1 &  0 & 3&&&&&& \\
&&N-2 &  0& \ldots&&&&& \\
&&&\vdots & \ddots &&&&& \\
&&&&& 0 & N-2 && \\
&&&&&3 & 0 &N-1 & \\
&&&&&&2 & 0&N  \\
&&&&&&& 1 &0 \\
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation}

where only nonzero entries are shown.

This matrix has size $(N+1) \times (N+1)$. Its superdiagonal entries grow linearly from $1$ to $N$, and the subdiagonal entries decrease linearly from $N$ to $1$.

Comment: I have found something similar on the stack exchange but I can't see how to generalize it to this case: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495534/eigenvalues-of-a-tridiagonal-stochastic-matrix

Comment: See [J.M.'s comment](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340594/calculating-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix/340611#comment868547_340611) to my answer in another thread.

Comment: @kotomord What's the point of this bounty? As mentioned by J.M. in his comment, the eigenvectors are the columns of a Krawtchouk matrix. See e.g. sec. 4 of the Feinsilver and Kocik paper in one of his links.

Comment: See : [Calculating the eigenvalues of a matrix](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/340594/calculating-the-eigenvalues-of-a-matrix) .

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Any interest to answer this bounty question? I think your inputs are invaluable.

Comment: I've read your answer and J.M.'s comment, and now I'm clear about the problem. Thank you!

Comment: In what sense is this matrix stochastic? It seems fully deterministic to me once $N$ is specified, so is $N$ a random variable? And then do you want the expectation of the largest eigenvalue over some distribution for $N$?

Answer (score 3):

Let $T$ be a tridiagonal matrix of order $m\times m$ such that the entries
$T_{i+1,i}$ and $T_{i,i+1}$ are positive for all $i$. Let $p_r$ be the characteristic
polynomial of the leading principal $r\times r$ submatrix of $T$ and set $p_0=1$.
Then the polynomials $p_1,\ldots,p_m$ satisfy a three-term recurrence, and it follows
that if $\theta$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then the vector with entries
\[
  p_0(\theta),\ldots,p_{n-1}(\theta)
\]
is an eigenvector for $T$ with eigenvalue $\theta$. (All this works for any tridiagonal
matrix $T$ such that $T_{i+1,i}T_{i,i+1}>0$ for all $i$. This is part of the theory of
orthogonal polynomials.)

For your choice of $T$, the eigenvalues are the integers $n-2k$ for $k=0,\ldots,n$
and the polynomials $p_r$ are known as *Krawtchouk polynomials*. We have (following wikipedia
for example) that
\[
  p_r(t) = \sum_{i=0}^r -1)^i \binom{t}{i} \binom{n-t}{r-i}.
\]

The best reference I know for Krawtchouk polynomials is MacWilliams and Sloane's book on coding theory, I could not find anything really useful online.

Comment: With regards to online references, Krawtchouk polynomials do show up in the DLMF under the rubric of the Hahn class in the Askey scheme of OPs (sections 18.19-18.24) ([Figure 18.21.1](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.21#F1) shows their place in the Askey scheme). In particular, it includes a discussion of their asymptotic behavior in section 18.24 along with citations to relevant papers.

Comment: @Semiclassical:  There is a fair bit of information out there, but I could not find something like a tutorial for someone starting from scratch. (Which surprises me.)