# Eigenvalues of a certain symmetric tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

Is there any way that can explicitly calculate eigenvalues (or at least the largest eigenvalue) of the following $n \times n$ symmetric matrix:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & \cdots  \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \cdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots 
\end{pmatrix}

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/495534/eigenvalues-of-a-tridiagonal-stochastic-matrix?rq=1

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix#Similarity_to_symmetric_tridiagonal_matrix

Comment: @SungjinKim, thanks, this helps a lot!